# Pandas Dataframe - Row Iteration with Resetting Count-Value by Condition without loop

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I work with Pandas and I am trying to create a vector where the value is increased and especially reset by condition. Due to a big amount of data I need an alternative to loops. I couldn't find any case where the 'count'-value is reset and starts to count again by condition without using a loop.

Input data:

```
Out[73]: 
    Time  Force
0      1    -10
1      2     -8
2      3    -12
3      4    -30
4      5     12
5      6     16
6      7     -8
7      8    -10
8      9    -40
9     10    -50
10    11    -60
11    12    -70
12    13    -50
13    14    -10
```

I want to create a new vector 'count' where the value is increased when the 'Force'-value is between -5 and -15. When it's outside this threshold the 'Count'-value is reset to 0 and starts again to Count() when it's inside the threshold.

What I would like to have:

```
    Time  Force  Count
0      1    -10      1
1      2     -8      2
2      3    -12      3
3      4    -30      0
4      5     12      0
5      6     16      0
6      7     -8      1
7      8    -10      2
8      9    -40      0
9     10    -50      0
10    11    -60      0
11    12    -70      0
12    13    -50      0
13    14    -10      1
```

Comment: so -8 to -12 is increase ?

Comment: Yes you're right Wen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,

```
mask = ((df.Force > -15) & (df.Force < -5))

df['count'] = mask.groupby((~mask).cumsum()).cumsum().astype(int)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Time  Force  count
0      1    -10      1
1      2     -8      2
2      3    -12      3
3      4    -30      0
4      5     12      0
5      6     16      0
6      7     -8      1
7      8    -10      2
8      9    -40      0
9     10    -50      0
10    11    -60      0
11    12    -70      0
12    13    -50      0
13    14    -10      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method using a loop:

```
# Give default value to "Count"
df['Count'] = 0
# Boolean 1 or 0
df['range'] = df['Force'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > -15 and x < -5 else 0)
# Accounting for edge case with check on first row.
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if (i == 0) and (df.iloc[0]['range'] == 1):
        df.loc[i, 'Count'] = 1
    if  (i != 0) and (df.loc[i, 'range'] == 1):
        df.loc[i, 'Count'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Count'] + df.loc[i, 'range']
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'Count'] == 0
df.drop('range', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
      Time  Force  Count
0      1    -10      1
1      2     -8      2
2      3    -12      3
3      4    -30      0
4      5     12      0
5      6     16      0
6      7     -8      1
7      8    -10      2
8      9    -40      0
9     10    -50      0
10    11    -60      0
11    12    -70      0
12    13    -50      0
13    14    -10      1
```

Comment: Due to a big amount of data a solution without a loop is the better way for me. Nevertheless thank you for your fast answer. For me as a beginner it's a good exercise to do it that way.