# Cumulative count resetting to and staying 0 based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a column 'count' on a pandas DF that cumulatively counts when field 'boolean' is True but resets and stays at 0 when 'boolean' is False. Also needs to be grouped by the ID column, so the count resets when looking at a new ID. No loops please as working with a big data set

Used the code from the following question which works but need to add a group by to include the ID column grouping

[Pandas Dataframe - Row Iteration with Resetting Count-Value by Condition without loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370211/pandas-dataframe-row-iteration-with-resetting-count-value-by-condition-without)

Expected output below: (ID, Boolean columns already exist, just need to create Count)

```
ID  Boolean  Count
1   True     1
1   True     2
1   True     3
1   True     4
1   True     5
1   False    0
1   False    0 
1   False    0
1   False    0
1   True     1
1   True     2
1   True     3
2   True     1
2   True     2
2   True     3
2   True     4
2   False    0
2   False    0
2   False    0
2   True     1
2   True     2
2   True     3
```

Comment: can you include code segments for how you're grouping and counting by condition

Comment: grp = (DF["Boolean"] == True)
DF["count"] = mask.groupby((~grp).cumsum()).cumsum().astype(int)

The above code works for the first ID but will continue to count True values cumulatively for ID = 2. Need it to reset and run separately for ID = 2

Answer (score 1):

Identify blocks by using `cumsum` on inverted boolean mask, then group the dataframe by `ID` and blocks and use `cumsum` on `Boolean` to create a counter

```
b = (~df['Boolean']).cumsum()
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['ID', b])['Boolean'].cumsum()
```

---

```
    ID  Boolean  Count
0    1     True      1
1    1     True      2
2    1     True      3
3    1     True      4
4    1     True      5
5    1    False      0
6    1    False      0
7    1    False      0
8    1    False      0
9    1     True      1
10   1     True      2
11   1     True      3
12   2     True      1
13   2     True      2
14   2     True      3
15   2     True      4
16   2    False      0
17   2    False      0
18   2    False      0
19   2     True      1
20   2     True      2
21   2     True      3
```

Comment: do you know how i can  reset to 1 instead of 0 when looking at a new ID? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby('ID')['Boolean'].diff()
df = df.fillna(False)
df['Count'] = df.groupby('ID')['Count'].cumsum()
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Count'])['Boolean'].cumsum()
df
```

---

```
    ID  Boolean  Count
0    1     True      1
1    1     True      2
2    1     True      3
3    1     True      4
4    1     True      5
5    1    False      0
6    1    False      0
7    1    False      0
8    1    False      0
9    1     True      1
10   1     True      2
11   1     True      3
12   2     True      1
13   2     True      2
14   2     True      3
15   2     True      4
16   2    False      0
17   2    False      0
18   2    False      0
19   2     True      1
20   2     True      2
21   2     True      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a column shift for `ID` and `Boolean` columns to identify the groups to do the `groupby` on.  Then do a `cumsum` for each of those groups.

```
groups = ((df['ID']!=df['ID'].shift()) | (df['Boolean']!=df['Boolean'].shift())).cumsum()

df.assign(Count2=df.groupby(groups)['Boolean'].cumsum())
```

**Result**

```
    ID  Boolean  Count  Count2
0    1     True      1       1
1    1     True      2       2
2    1     True      3       3
3    1     True      4       4
4    1     True      5       5
5    1    False      0       0
6    1    False      0       0
7    1    False      0       0
8    1    False      0       0
9    1     True      1       1
10   1     True      2       2
11   1     True      3       3
12   2     True      1       1
13   2     True      2       2
14   2     True      3       3
15   2     True      4       4
16   2    False      0       0
17   2    False      0       0
18   2    False      0       0
19   2     True      1       1
20   2     True      2       2
21   2     True      3       3
```